# Find multiple records with same Id in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Find multiple records with same Id in SQL server

I have following value in my table

```
PK  Id  Value1  Value2
1   1     5      10
2   1     10     10
3   2     5      20
4   3     20     25
5   3     5      5
6   4     10     10
7   1     5      20
8   4     5      10
9   2     25     30
10  5     25     30
11  5     5      20
12  5     5      5
```

I want to get 'Id' column which have two record with some values like  (First Record) Value1 = 5, Value2 = 20 and (Second Record) Value1 =25,  Value2 = 30.

In Above table my expected result is

```
PIds    Id  Value1  Value2
3       2     5      20
9       2     25     30
10      5     25     30
11      5     5      20
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what should be o/p from this table ?

Comment: PLease explain what you are trying to do. What is the general case here? Why @techdo 's answer is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select * from YourTable
where 
    (Value1=5 and Value2=20) OR 
    (Value1 =25 and Value2 = 30)
```

Comment: This is right answer but in my case records can be 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: I dint get you. Please explain.

Comment: I have added result set which I want.  Your query will show 1 Id record because of OR condition

Answer (score 0):

All other query shows 1, 2 and 5 Ids

I have found this query for my problem

```
select T1.Id,* from TestData T1 inner join TestData T2
on T1.Id = T2.Id
where 
    (T2.Value1=5 and T2.Value2=20) and
    (T1.Value1=25 and T1.Value2 = 30)
```